# Factoring out common components when kustomizing kubernetes manifests

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

I'm using kustomize binary to craft specific kubernetes deployment yaml files.

> {Version:kustomize/v3.8.1
> GitCommit:0b359d0ef0272e6545eda0e99aacd63aef99c4d0
> BuildDate:2020-07-16T00:58:46Z GoOs:linux GoArch:amd64}

Here is my directory structure:

```
overlays
├── parser
│   ├── dev
│   │   └── nonsec
│   │       ├── dev-patches-parsers-tests.yaml
│   │       ├── dev-patches-parsers.yaml
│   │       └── kustomization.yaml
│   ├── prod
│   │   ├── nonsec
│   │   │   ├── kustomization.yaml
│   │   │   ├── prod-patches-parsers-tests.yaml
│   │   │   └── prod-patches-parsers.yaml
│   │   ├── sec
│   │   │   ├── kustomization.yaml
│   │   │   ├── prod-patches-parsers-sec-tests.yaml
│   │   │   ├── prod-patches-parsers-sec.yaml
│   │   │   ├── prod-patches-parsers-tests.yaml
│   │   │   └── prod-patches-parsers.yaml
│   │   └── v3r
│   │       └── empty.txt
│   ├── stage

│   └── suit
```

Notice that overlays/parser/prod/nonsec and /overlays/parser/prod/sec contain two identical patch file sets.  I want to factor out the common files and push them up one level under prod - I don't want copies of same patches in multiple dirs.   I want both nonsec and sec builds to use the same set of prod-patches but I don't know how to do that with kustomize.  I've tried to put them in the dir above, but kustomize   doesn't allow any references to patch files in the directories above - which is what I NEED to do.

How can I avoid duplication of these prod-patches*.yaml files in multiple dirs?!

Here is my nonsec kustomization.yaml

```
# Use this as the base code
resources:
  - ../../../../base

# Decorate the base code with the following components
components:
  - ../../../../components/common-all
  - ../../../../components/common-prod
  - ../../../../components/parser

# Then finally, patch the results from above with this:
patchesStrategicMerge:
 - prod-patches-parsers.yaml
 - prod-patches-parsers-tests.yaml
```

And this is my sec kustomization.yaml:

```
# Use this as the base code
resources:
  - ../../../../base

# Decorate the base code with the following components
components:
  - ../../../../components/common-all
  - ../../../../components/common-prod
  - ../../../../components/parser

# Then finally, patch the results from above with this:
patchesStrategicMerge:
 - prod-patches-parsers.yaml
 - prod-patches-parsers-tests.yaml
 - prod-patches-parsers-sec.yaml
 - prod-patches-parsers-sec-tests.yaml
```

Comment: I solved it 'temporarily':  I moved the two patch files up under prod folder and created hard links to them under nonsec, sec and vr3 folders.   It works though it's a bit 'hacky' - also, note that the -s soft link would NOT work, I had to resort to hard links for this.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
overlays
├── parser
│   ├── dev
│   │   └── nonsec
│   │       ├── dev-patches-parsers-tests.yaml
│   │       ├── dev-patches-parsers.yaml
│   │       └── kustomization.yaml
│   ├── prod
│   │   ├── kustomization.yaml
│   │   ├── prod-patches-parsers-tests.yaml
│   │   ├── prod-patches-parsers.yaml
│   │   ├── nonsec
│   │   │   └── kustomization.yaml
│   │   ├── sec
│   │   │   ├── kustomization.yaml
│   │   │   ├── prod-patches-parsers-sec-tests.yaml
│   │   │   └── prod-patches-parsers-sec.yaml
│   │   └── v3r
│   │       └── empty.txt
```

with `overlays/parser/prod/kustomization.yaml`:

```yaml
resources:
  - ../../../../base
  - ../../../../components/common-all
  - ../../../../components/common-prod
  - ../../../../components/parser

patchesStrategicMerge:
  - prod-patches-parsers.yaml
  - prod-patches-parsers-tests.yaml
```

`overlays/parser/prod/nonsec/kustomization.yaml`:

```yaml
resources:
  - ../
```

`overlays/parser/prod/sec/kustomization.yaml`:

```yaml
resources:
  - ../

patchesStrategicMerge:
  - prod-patches-parsers.yaml
  - prod-patches-parsers-tests.yaml
```

The overall directory structure is a bit complex and you might want to simplify or flatten it.